# aws: "Matched event" in a CloudWatch Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I am following the official `aws` [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/bouncecomplaintdashboard.html) on how to automate handling of email bounces and complaints and have a custom html report generated.

I used the `CloudFormation` [template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/master/SES/SESReports/ses-reports.yaml) as provided by Amazon.

This created among other things a `CloudWatch` rule that uses as target a `lambda` [function](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/raw/master/SES/SESReports/sesreport.zip) (also provided by amazon).

When following the official testing [procedures](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dashboardtestlambdafunction.html), I am instructed to run `Test` on the created `lambda` but this requires as input, a so called test event (guidelines by amazon do not clarify this issue).

- What event should I choose to test the function?
- What is the "Matched Event" entry in the `CloudWatch` rule created?

Comment: 1. The lambda create instructions, do have instructions to configure the test event. "On the Configure test event window, for Event name, type a name, and then choose Create."

How this input event is used would depend on the code in lambda. 

2. The matched event entry can be a regex which is constantly matched with your cloudwatch api logs and once the condition is satisfied it send the event downstream - maybe a sns topic or lambda etc.